# Why doesn't * as a command line parameter to "java" work as expected?

Tags: java

I have a program that takes in a string as parameter and the searches the string in a text file.

Everything works perfectly except when I enter `*` as the parameter. It prints out all the file name in my directory. Seems it doesn't go through the code when I enter `*` as the parameter.

Anyone know whats going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your shell is expanding the `*` before it gets to your program. Try escaping it like so

```
bash$ java MyClass \*
```

Comment: Thanks. \* works. so, this is my shell's problem? This is school assignment. I'm not sure if my professor is going to use * as the test case or not.

Comment: @John: Yes, this is something the shell does. It has nothing to do with your program. If your teacher is planning to pass "*" as a parameter, he will hopefully know how to operate his shell.

Answer (score 6):

You are most likely passing a glob of files from the command line.  This link might be of interest:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)#Syntax

Basically, when you say

```
java ... *
```

The `*` character is expanded (by your shell) into a list of files in the current directory.  This happens before java even sees the `*` character, and java instead sees "file1 file2 ...".

It may help to surround the `*` character with single quotes on the command line, like this:

```
'*'
```

or by escaping it:

```
\*
```

Answer (score 2):

**-** `*` has a special meaning in **Regular expressions.**

**-** So you must use `\\` before it.

**Eg:**

```
\\*
```